# Cylindrical coordinates and Differential Displacement: unit vectors and differentiation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, cylindrical-coordinates

### How to calculate the Differential Displacement (Path Increment)

**This is what it starts with:**
\begin{align}
\text{From the Cylindrical to the Rectangular coordinate system:}& \\
x&=\rho\cos\phi \\
y&=\rho\sin\phi \\
z&=z \\
& \\
\text{From the Rectangular to the Cylindrical coordinate system:}& \\
\rho&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \\
\phi&=\arctan(x,y) \\
z&=z \\
& \\
\text{Unit vectors:}& \\   
\hat{\rho}&=\frac{\vec{\rho}}{\rho}=\frac{x\,\hat{x}+y\,\hat{y}}{\rho}=\hat{x}\cos\phi+\hat{y}\sin\phi \\
\hat{\phi}&=\hat{z}\times\hat{\rho}=-\hat{x}\sin\phi+\hat{y}\cos\phi \\
\hat{z}&=\hat{z} \\
& \\
\text{Partial derivatives:}& \\
\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\rho}&=0 \\
\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\phi}&=-\hat{x}\sin\phi+\hat{y}\cos\phi \\
\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial{z}}&=0 \\
& \\
\frac{\partial\hat{\phi}}{\partial\rho}&=0 \\
\frac{\partial\hat{\phi}}{\partial\phi}&=-\hat{x}\cos\phi-\hat{y}\sin\phi=-\hat{\rho} \\
\frac{\partial\hat{\phi}}{\partial{z}}&=0 \\
& \\
\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\rho}&=0 \\
\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\phi}&=0 \\
\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial{z}}&=0 \\
& \\
\text{Differential Displacement (Path increment):}& \\
\vec{r}&=\rho\hat{\rho}+z\hat{z} \\
d\vec{r}&=d(\rho\hat{\rho}+z\hat{z})=\hat{\rho}\,d\rho+\rho\, d\hat{\rho}+\hat{z}\,dz+z\,d\hat{z} \\
& \\
\end{align}
**This is my question:**
This paper says:
\begin{align}
\hat{\rho}\,d\rho+\rho\,d\hat{\rho}+\hat{z}\,dz+z\,d\hat{z}&=\hat{\rho}\,d\rho+\rho(\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial z}dz)+\hat{z}\,dz+z(\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial z}dz) \\
\end{align}
What I don't get is why
$$d\hat{\rho}=\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial z}dz$$
And in the same vein, why
$$d\hat{z}=\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial z}dz\quad\text{?}$$

**The road to a solution:**
The derivative of a position vector $\vec{r}$, with respect to coordinate value $l$ (where $l\in\{x,y,z,\rho,\phi,r,\theta\}$) is expressed as:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial l}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial l}(x\hat{a}_x+y\hat{a}_y+z\hat{a}_z) \\
&=\frac{\partial(x\hat{a}_x)}{\partial l}+\frac{\partial(y\hat{a}_y)}{\partial l}+\frac{\partial(z\hat{a}_z)}{\partial l} \\
&=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial l}\right)\hat{a}_x+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial l}\right)\hat{a}_y+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial l}\right)\hat{a}_z \\
\end{align}
If a point moves such that its coordinate $l$ changes from $l$ to $l+\Delta$, then the position vector that describes that point changes from $\vec{r}$ to $\vec{r}+\vec{\Delta l}$.
This vector $\vec{\Delta l}$ is a **directed distance** between the vector $\vec{r}$ at coordinate $l$ and the new vector $\vec{r}+\vec{\Delta l}$ at coordinate $l+\Delta l$!
This directed distance $\vec{\Delta l}$ is related to the position vector derivative as:
\begin{align}
\vec{\Delta l}&=\Delta l \frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial l} \\
&=\Delta l\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial l}\right)\hat{a}_x+\Delta l\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial l}\right)\hat{a}_y+\Delta l\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial l}\right)\hat{a}_z \\
\end{align}
As an **example**, consider the case when $l=\rho$.
Since $x=\rho\cos\phi$ and $y=\rho\sin\phi$ we find that:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial\rho}&=\frac{\partial x}{\partial\rho}\hat{a}_x+\frac{\partial y}{\partial\rho}\hat{a}_y+\frac{\partial z}{\partial\rho}\hat{a}_z \\
&=\frac{\partial(\rho\cos\phi)}{\partial\rho}\hat{a}_x+\frac{\partial(\rho\sin\phi)}{\partial\rho}\hat{a}_y+\frac{\partial z}{\partial\rho}\hat{a}_z \\
&=(\cos\phi)\,\hat{a}_x+(\sin\phi)\,\hat{a}_y \\
&=\hat{a}_\rho \\
&=\hat{\rho}
\end{align}
A change in position from coordinates $\rho,\phi,z$ to $\rho+\Delta \rho,\phi,z$ results in a change in the position vector from $\vec{r}$ to $\vec{r}+\vec{\Delta l}$.
The vector $\vec{\Delta l}$ is a directed distance extending from point $\rho,\phi,z$ to point $\rho+\Delta \rho,\phi,z$, and is equal to:
\begin{align}
\vec{\Delta l}&=\Delta \rho\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial\rho} \\
&=\Delta \rho\,(\cos\phi)\,\hat{a}_x+\Delta \rho\,(\sin\phi)\,\hat{a}_y \\
&=\Delta \rho\,\hat{a}_\rho \\
&=\Delta \rho\,\hat{\rho}
\end{align}
If $\Delta l$ is really small (i.e., as it approaches zero) we can define something called a **differential displacement vector** $\vec{dl}$:
\begin{align}
\vec{dl}&\doteq\lim\limits_{\Delta l \to 0}\vec{\Delta l} \\
&=\lim\limits_{\Delta l \to 0}\Delta l\left(\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial l}\right) \\
&=\lim\limits_{\Delta l \to 0}\left(\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial l}\right)\Delta l \\
&=\left(\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial l}\right)dl
\end{align}
Using this, the differential displacement vectors for the cylindrical coordinate system are therefore:
\begin{align}
\vec{d\rho}&=\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial\rho}d\rho \\
&=\hat{a}_\rho \,d\rho \\
&=\hat{\rho}\,d\rho \\
& \\
\vec{d\phi}&=\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial\phi}d\phi \\
&=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial\phi}\hat{a}_x+\frac{\partial y}{\partial\phi}\hat{a}_y+\frac{\partial z}{\partial\phi}\hat{a}_z\right)d\phi \\
&=\left(\frac{\partial\rho\cos\phi}{\partial\phi}\hat{a}_x+\frac{\partial\rho\sin\phi}{\partial\phi}\hat{a}_y+\frac{\partial z}{\partial\phi}\hat{a}_z\right)d\phi \\
&=\left(-\rho\,(\sin\phi)\,\hat{a}_x +\rho\,(\cos\phi)\,\hat{a}_y\right)d\phi \\
&=\left(-(\sin\phi)\,\hat{a}_x+(\cos\phi)\,\hat{a}_y\right)\rho \,d\phi \\
&=\hat{a}_\phi \,\rho \,d\phi \\
&=\hat{\phi}\,\rho\,d\phi \\
& \\
\vec{dz}&=\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial z}dz \\
&=\hat{a}_z \,dz \\
&=\hat{z}\,dz \\
\end{align}
This I got from [this site](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/220/handouts/section_2_5_The_Calculus_of_Vector_Fields_package1.pdf).

**Solution?:**
Thanks for the tip, [narasimham](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/95860/narasimham).

The **total derivative** of a function is different from its corresponding partial derivative ($\partial$). Calculation of the total derivative of $f$ with respect to $t$ does not assume that the other arguments are constant while $t$ varies; instead, it assumes that the other arguments too depend on $t$.

Remember that:
$$\hat{\phi}=-\hat{x}\sin\phi+\hat{y}\cos\phi$$

Then, this means that:
\begin{align} 
d\hat{\rho}&=\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial z}dz \\
&=0\cdot d\rho+(-\hat{x}\sin\phi+\hat{y}\cos\phi)\,d\phi+0\cdot dz \\
&=\hat{\phi}\,d\phi \\
\end{align} 
And:
\begin{align} 
d\hat{z}&=\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial z}dz \\
&=0\cdot d\rho+0\cdot d\phi+ 0\cdot dz \\
&=0 \\
\end{align}

So:
\begin{align}
\hat{\rho}\,d\rho+\rho \,d\hat{\rho}+\hat{z}\,dz+z\,d\hat{z}&=\hat{\rho}\,d\rho+\rho(\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial\phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial\hat{\rho}}{\partial z}dz)+\hat{z}\,dz+z(\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\rho}d\rho+\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial\phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial\hat{z}}{\partial z}dz) \\
&=\hat{\rho}\,d\rho+\rho(\hat{\phi}\,d\phi)+\hat{z}\,dz+\hat{z}\cdot0 \\
&=\hat{\rho}\,d\rho+\hat{\phi}\,\rho\,d\phi+\hat{z}\,dz \\
\end{align}
Which is eqal to the summation of the differential displacement vectors calculated above.

Comment: The total differential is considerd  in this way in multivariarible calculus by the definition of a derivative.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!